# How do you export/download the file of an already-installed plugin?

Tags: plugins

I have a plugin I modified and I want to download a copy of it because it is different than the original version available for download from the plugin store. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You could use cPanel if you have it - go to the file manager, open `wp-content/plugins` and ZIP/compress the plugin folder, then just download the file. Alternatively, use an FTP client like FileZilla to manually download the whole folder to your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FTP to get these files. Plugins are stored in 'wp-content/plugins' directory. All you have to know is the name of its directory/file.

PS. You should never modify original plugins. You will loose ability to update such plugin and updates are crucial for security.